# City <-> Zipcode database design

Tags: database, database-design

I need to create a database containing all cities and zip codes worldwide. For that I want to create a table 'city' and a table zip_code. My question is, how is the relation between city and zip code, is it worldwide an 1:n relationship or can it also be m:n in some countries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It differs. In Holland we got multiple zipcodes per street, most of the time. The zip codes are so fine grained (consisting of 4 digits + 2 letters), that just the zipcode and the address house number is enough to uniquely identify a building.

In Belgium, though, there's a 4 digit postal code, and a couple of towns can have the same zipcode, while it is still possible that a larger city has multiple zipcodes. It can even happen that a city has multiple zipcodes, while each (or some) of them are shared with some smaller towns as well.

So I would almost say that there is not relation between zip code and city, or at least no one definition that works on a global scale. If you would store it in a database, then it's definately a m:n relation.

Answer (score 4):

For the US at least it is a M:M. A city can have multiplle zips, and a zip can cover more than  one city, (Obviously depending on how loosly you define a city vs a town or a municipality).